# Strapi deployed to Heroku but media files give 404 error

Tags: strapi

I've deployed Strapi on Heroku and have set up the content fine. When I uploaded images and videos to Strapi using the cms interface and saved the update. it saved successfully but the file url returns 404. has anyone experienced this before? Am I missing something?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#file-uploads

File Uploads

Like with project updates on Heroku, the file system doesn't support local uploading of files as they will be wiped when Heroku "Cycles" the dyno. This type of file system is called ephemeral, which means the file system only lasts until the dyno is restarted (with Heroku this happens any time you redeploy or during their regular restart which can happen every few hours or every day).

Due to Heroku's filesystem you will need to use an upload provider such as AWS S3, Cloudinary, or Rackspace. You can view the documentation for installing providers here and you can see a list of providers from both Strapi and the community on npmjs.com.